# Flutter/provider- initializing a state with a constructor

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

i am trying to understand how provider works in flutter and still i haven't figured out how to initialize a state using the state's constructor. Any tip?

here is the class the constructor is monitoring

```
class Counter extends ChangeNotifier{
  int _count;
  
  Counter(int initValue){

  _count=initValue;
  }
  
  void increment() {
    ++_count;
    notifyListeners();
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

First, you can simplify your ChangeNotifier to:

```dart
class Counter extends ChangeNotifier {
  int count;

  Counter(this.count);

  void increment() {
    count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

### 1. Create your `ChangeNotifierProvider`

Now, define your `ChangeNotifierProvider` as:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
  create: (context) => Counter(10),
  child: child,
),
```

This is where you provide the initial value of your `Counter`.

### 2. Consume your `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

```dart
Consumer<Counter>(
  builder: (context, counter, child) => Text(counter.count.toString()),
```

### 3. Increment your `ChangeNotifier` `Counter`

```dart
Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false).increment(),
```

Here, remember to specify that you do not want to listen to your Provider.

### Full source Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
      create: (context) => Counter(10),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'StackOverflow Answer',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Consumer<Counter>(
            builder: (context, counter, child) => Text(
              counter.count.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () =>
              Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false).increment(),
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Counter extends ChangeNotifier {
  int count;

  Counter(this.count);

  void increment() {
    count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

## Riverpod

Note: If you are learning `Provider`, have a look at the [Riverpod package](http://riverpod.dev/), from the same author as `Provider`. It's much simpler, with less boiler plate:

Here is the same example using Hooks Riverpod.

### 1. Create your `ChangeNotifierProvider`

The Provider is just a global variable that exists within the `ProviderScope` that we define on top of our `MyApp`.

```dart
final counterProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>((ref) => Counter(10));
```

### 2. Consume your `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

With Hooks Riverpos, consuming the Provider is made with `useProvider` at the beginning of the build method:

```dart
final counter = useProvider(counterProvider);
```

### 3. Increment your `ChangeNotifier` `Counter`

This is as easy as reading the `Provider` from the current `BuildContext` and calling the method `increment`:

```dart
context.read(counterProvider).increment(),
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'StackOverflow Answer', home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = useProvider(counterProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          counter.count.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context.read(counterProvider).increment(),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final counterProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>((ref) => Counter(10));

class Counter extends ChangeNotifier {
  int count;

  Counter(this.count);

  void increment() {
    count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```