# Flutter Provider initialize default state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a Provider that I was creating with:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<WeekList>(create: (context) => WeekList()
```

But I wanted to initialize the list with adding one week to it at the start. I was pretty stumbed until I read this Stack Overflow article: [Flutter/provider- initializing a state with a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619564/flutter-provider-initializing-a-state-with-a-constructor)

But then when I tried it myself with:

```
    ChangeNotifierProvider<WeekList>(create: (context) => WeekList().addWeek(budget: 300.00)),
```

I got this error:

> The return type 'void' isn't a 'WeekList', as required by the
> closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure

Since its a void I tried removing the type like this:

```
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => WeekList().addWeek(budget: 300.00)),
```

But that also did not work.

My WeekList class is:

```
class WeekList extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Week> listOfWeeks = [];

  void addWeek({
    required double budget,
  }) {
    Week newWeek = Week(
      budget: budget,
    );
    listOfWeeks.add(newWeek);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: How about doing inside notifier `List<Week> listOfWeeks = [Week()];` or using on constructor body.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sorry, not exactly sure what you mean by that suggestion.

Comment: Please try this `ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) { WeekList weekList = WeekList(); weekList.addWeek(budget: 300.00); return weekList;  }) ,`

Comment: @Mardel I had to edit some formatting as the code was missing a ) but it worked! Thanks so much! Care to explain what I was doing wrong and how your code works?

Comment: We need to return WeekList object, but in your previous code, you didn't return anything. Otherwise, you call addWeek function and it doesn't mean to return WeekList object. That's all. Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `create` you need to return a WeekList.
The function `addWeek` has a type of `void` not `WeekList`.
You can change that function to return `WeekList` that will then create the `ChangeNotifierProvider` with the listOfWeeks containing the newWeek because now the listOfWeeks will be returned.

```dart
class WeekList extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Week> listOfWeeks = [];

  WeekList createWeekList({
    required double budget,
  }) {
    Week newWeek = Week(
      budget: budget,
    );
    listOfWeeks.add(newWeek);
    return listOfWeeks; 
  }
}
```

An other option is to initialise the `listOfWeeks` with a `Week` and then not use `addWeek` in `create`

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<WeekList>(create: (context) => WeekList())

...

class WeekList extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Week> listOfWeeks = [Week(budget: budget: 300.00)];

  void addWeek({
    required double budget,
  }) {
    Week newWeek = Week(
      budget: budget,
    );
    listOfWeeks.add(newWeek);
    
  }
}
```

And another option if you need specify the budget amount would be to initials `WeekList` with a budget amount.

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<WeekList>(create: (context) => WeekList(budget: 300.00))

...

class WeekList extends ChangeNotifier {
  final double budget;
  const WeekList({required this.budget}){
    listOfWeeks = [Week(budget: budget: budget)]
  }
  Late final List<Week> listOfWeeks;

  void addWeek({
    required double budget,
  }) {
    Week newWeek = Week(
      budget: budget,
    );
    listOfWeeks.add(newWeek);
    
  }
}
```

Then there is one more option i can think of and that is to use the cascade notation.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation
Which would look like this.

```dart
 ChangeNotifierProvider<WeekList>(create: (context) => WeekList()..addWeek(budget: 300.00)),
```

Comment: but then that code really isnt a"AddWeek" it just returns and doesn't do the add function.

Comment: It does add the week, but it also returns the updated list maybe changing the name of the function would be better. Updated the answer.

Comment: Gotcha, I see it now! Still changes the functionality a bit for that function though.

Comment: Updated answer with different options.

Comment: Awesome will try this out in a bit and let you know!